# Input sanitization for database interaction in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

In commands like this in zend framework

`$mapperObject->fetchAll($where, $order, $count, $offset);`

Does one need to be careful about what the variables contain or ZF will take care of it for sql injection and all that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is using the standard `Zend_Db_Table->fetchAll`, then you are indeed protected from SQL injection as long as you use the secure methods for creating your parameters eg:

```
 $where = $select->where('id = ?', $id);
 // or ..
 $where = $select->where('id = :id');
```

and not

```
 $where = $select->where('id = $id');
```